# Decode JSON stringify in a different php file

Tags: php, json

```
<script>
function getstaff(){
var staffinfo = $('#group').val();
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(staffinfo);
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{data:myJSONText},
    url:"staffDetails.php",
    success: function(result){
    alert(result);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

How do I retrieve the posted data in staffDetails.php file.  It some how gives me drastic errors. Can anyone suggest how exactly to retrieve what I sent to this php file

```
<?php
$data = JSON.parse($_POST['data'],',');
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: json_decode($_POST['data']);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `json_decode` to decode a json array in `PHP`

```
 $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: When you save some data using JSON.stringify() and then need to read that in php. The following code worked for me.   json_decode( html_entity_decode( stripslashes ($jsonString ) ) );

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true); 
print_f($data); // return data in associative array.

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is function:

```
json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

use it.

```
JSON.parse
```

is the  function of Javascript so it will not work in php.

Read this: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have array like

```js
`{"1":{"1":"Employer+EID","2":"File+Creation+Date","3":"File+Creation+Time","4":"Payer+EID","5":"Payer+QID","6":"Payer+Bank+Short+Name","7":"Payer+IBAN","8":"Salary+Year+and+Montd","9":"Total+Salaries","10":"Total+records","11":"","12":"","13":"","14":"","15":""}}
```

you can read in php with :

$data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

echo $data[1][1];
use logic to cycle through data.